# Simple factory setter/getter in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, factory, setter, getter

I have this factory...

```
spa.factory("currentPageFactory", function() {
    var pageDefinition = {};
    pageDefinition.save = function(newPageDefinition) {
        pageDefinition.value = newPageDefinition;
    }
    pageDefinition.read = function() {
        return pageDefinition.value;
    }
    return pageDefinition;
});
```

...and this controller...

```
var pageDefinitionController = spa.controller("pageDefinitionController", ["currentPageFactory", function(currentPageFactory) {

        currentPageFactory.save("foobar");
}]);
```

I have tested using the `.read()` function I created in this factory by including a definition in the factory of `pageDefinition.value`. I could read the variable using the getter just fine. The problem seems to lie in the setter.

I'm calling these functions like this...

```
/*Setter Call Example*/
currentPageFactory.save("blah");

/*Getter Call Example*/
this.foobar = currentPageFactory.read();
```

What am I doing wrong? Why is the setter not working?

Comment: So what exactly doesn't work? The code is fine.

Comment: Works fine here - http://jsfiddle.net/pqwq8qc6/

Comment: Really strange. It's not working on my site at all. The save function is included in a controller which is never put in an html attribute. I.E. the name of the controller that contains the save function call is never put in a "ng-controller" attribute on my HTML page. Is this the reason?

Comment: @Allenph Probably. `pageDefinitionController` needs to be called from somewhere, either an `ng-route` or an `ng-controller` attribute

Comment: That's not the problem either. I added it to `ng-controller` on the `<html>` tag.

Comment: I lied. That was indeed the problem.